# Does Ember have the equivalent of ruby's method_missing?

Tags: ember.js

I have a wrapper class that returns boolean flag values based on data provided by the server.  I would like to not have to define a property for each flag since there will be many of them and they will be frequently created and destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So glad you asked!

You can define `unknownProperty`, which will be called if a property that is not defined is accessed via `get`.

```
unknownProperty: (key) ->
  #handle it
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.EachProxy.html#method_unknownProperty

Similarly there is `setUnknownProperty` for `set` calls on undefined properties.

```
setUnknownProperty: (key, value) ->
  #handle it
```

Comment: Why do you answer yourself like if it's not you who wrote the question? :)

Comment: I just found it amusing.  No intention of misleading people.